# PHP Looping through dates causes error

Tags: php, date, loops

Can anyone tell me why the following fails when the date is >= 2013-01-06

It's so weird, when ever the date is after this date the script works perfectly but anything before and I get the white screen of death!

```
<?php 

use Carbon\Carbon;

$startDate    = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-01-06');
$current_week = Carbon::now()->timestamp;

/*
$startDate    = strtotime('2013-01-06');
$current_week = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
*/

$weeks        = array();
$w            = 0;

while($startDate < $current_week){
    $weeks[$w] = array(
        'monday' => $startDate->startofWeek()->format('d/m/Y'), 
        'sunday' => $startDate->endofWeek()->format('d/m/Y')
    );
    $w++;
    $startDate = $startDate->addDays(1); // Move it on to the following week
}

var_dump($weeks);

?>
```

Please can someone help me?!

Comment: What is appearing in your server's error log?

Comment: Can you put up a demo online somewhere?

Comment: shouldn't you add 7 days to your start date to move to the following week (rather than 1)?  Not knowing more about Carbon, I'm going to have to guess that your issue is a bug in Carbon.

Comment: @MikeW I'm getting this error [27-Oct-2013 14:14:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/date/app/views/hello.php on line 14

Comment: You are doing an infinite loop here...

Comment: Something is not right, since you're running out of memory. I don't see anything here that can't be done with `DateTime`. Have you tried an implementation without using Carbon?

Comment: @jacouh How is it an infinite loop? Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @Glavić i'm getting the same error

Comment: @bencarter78: why are you reposting your same question? Did you try my [code](https://eval.in/57880)?

Answer (score 1):

This ? We compare timestamp with timestamp, not a datetime object with timestamp, I don't know Carbon class, here $startDate->timestamp must be replaced by the method converting carbon datetime object to unix timestamp.

```
<?php 

use Carbon\Carbon;

$startDate    = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-01-06');
$startDateTimestamp = $startDate->timestamp;
$current_week = Carbon::now()->timestamp;

/*
$startDate    = strtotime('2013-01-06');
$current_week = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
*/

$weeks        = array();
$w            = 0;

while($startDateTimestamp < $current_week){
    $weeks[$w] = array(
        'monday' => $startDate->startofWeek()->format('d/m/Y'), 
        'sunday' => $startDate->endofWeek()->format('d/m/Y')
    );
    $w++;
    $startDate = $startDate->addDays(7); // Move it on to the following week
    $startDateTimestamp = $startDate->timestamp;
}

var_dump($weeks);

?>
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error happening.

Comment: Please echo $current_week and in the infinite while loop, echo $startDateTimestamp if it increases. You are staying inside the while loop.